# Proving that solution of heat equation converges to the average temperature

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am trying to do the following exercise

> Consider the heat equation in one space dimension with homogeneous Neumann Boundary conditions : $u_t=cu_{xx}$ in $(0,L)\times (0,\infty), u(x,0)=u_0(x)$ for $x\in [0,L], u_{x}(0,t)=u_x(L,t)=0$ for $t\geq 0$ and let $u$ be a classical solution. Show that in the $L^2-$norm $u(x,t)\rightarrow U_0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$, where $U_0=\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^L u(x,t)dx$.

It's easy to see that the average temperature is conserved ,i.e., $\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^L u(x,t)dx = \frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^L u_0(x)dx$ for every $t>0$. And so if we consider $w(x,t):=u(x,t)-U_0$, we will have that for each $t$ there exists $x(t)$ such that $w(x(t),t)=0$.

Now I am trying to show that $E'(t)\leq -CE(t)$ for $E(t):=\int_{0}^L w^2(x,t)dx $, and then by Gronwall's inequality we will get the desired result.

All I have gotten is that $E'(t)= -2c\int_{0}^L w_x^2(x,t)dx$, and I don't know how to proceed from here.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest to use Fourier series to write an ansatz for the solution, prove it's in fact a solution, and then prove that the solution converges to its mean. In the periodic case it converges uniformly, but I think it is easy to check the $L^2$ convergence.

Comment: In any case, if $E'$ has the form that you have written, you can say that $E$ is a decreasing function of time. Then, it should converge to a positive number or to 0. Suppose if possible that that number is positive, then the $L^2$ norm of the derivative of $w$ is going to zero (you should make it rigorous) and I guess that using Holder, this implies that $w(x,t)$ is closer and closer to a constant for large $t$. This constant has to be 0 because the average temperature is conserved (again, you should make it rigorous).

Comment: I'm getting something a bit different for $E'$. I have
$$E'(t)=2c\int_0^L  w(x,t)\cdot \partial_x^2 w(x,t)\mathrm dx$$

Comment: Yes, then you can integrate by parts